# Configuring compiler optimization options in visual studio

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2015, compiler-optimization

Background:

I was having a hard time finding info on this so I was wondering if someone could help me out. Basically, I have a game engine project I'm creating for which I have two build targets currently, 'Debug' and 'Release' (pretty standard). I want to create a middle ground build target called 'Profile' which will still have more compiler optimizations than 'Debug' but less so than 'Release'. 'Profile' will give me the fastest development time while still providing me with basic debug functionality turned on.

Issue:

I'm not sure where I need to look or how I should go about creating my new build configuration in visual studio. Where do I select what compiler optimizations to turn off and on for my custom configuration? Is there a menu with a list somewhere? Keep in mind I'm talking about doing this through visual studio's gui and not command line.

Comment: In the project settings you can find somewhere the optimization level and change it, but there will not be a list of optimizations you can individually choose.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think, you are looking for this:[image]

It lists all possible options for optimizations in MSVC

Comment: Fantastic! Thank you.